# Execute ASP.nett codebehind method with Ajax Timer

Tags: ajax, vb.net, timer

I'm trying to get a timer to invoke a codebehind method after 5 seconds, but when the page is being loaded I get

Method 'Protected WithEvents timEndup As System.Web.UI.Timer' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(Of System.EventArgs)(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.

On the page I have

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:Timer runat="server" id="timEndup" interval="5000" ontick="timEndup" />
```

and in the codebehind I have

```
Private Sub timEndup_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timEndup.Tick
    Stop
End Sub
```

The signature looks correct to me, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already associated to an `EventHandler` your  `timEndup`’s `.Tick` `Event` by: `Handles timEndup.Tick` in code behind.

So, just remove `OnTick` attribute by client side, `OnTick="timEndup"` must be removed

Or remove: `Handles timEndup.Tick` by code behind and put in the `OnTick` attribute the real name of `EventHandler Sub` as `timEndup_Tick`

***So the code becomes:***

Client Side:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timEndup" Interval="5000"  OnTick="timEndup_Tick"  />
```

Server Side:

```
Protected Sub timEndup_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Debug.WriteLine("Tick ")
End Sub
```

***Or:***

Client Side:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timEndup" Interval="5000" />
```

Server Side:

```
 Protected Sub timEndup_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timEndup.Tick
      Debug.WriteLine("Tick ")
 End Sub
```

Another thing is that the `EventHandler Sub` must be declared NOT `Private`